# How to rewrite the ValueMapper Function using java lambda

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible/correct(to) or rewrite the below below using `lambda`? Here I have provided inline implementations for KeyMapper and ValueMapper `Function`.

```
public Map<Integer, List<Employee>> getSubordinateHighestSalEmpMapV1(List<Employee> employees) {

        return employees.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getSubordinates() != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap( //keyMapper
         new Function<Employee, Integer>() {

            @Override
            public Integer apply(Employee t) {
                return t.getId();
            }
        }, 
        new Function<Employee, List<Employee>>() {//valueMapper

            @Override
            public List<Employee> apply(Employee t) {
                List<Employee> subordinates = t.getSubordinates();
                List<Employee> subOrdinatesListWithHighestSalary = new ArrayList<>();
                int maxSal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                for(Employee s: subordinates) {
                    if(s.getSalary() >= maxSal) {
                        maxSal = s.getSalary();
                    }
                }
                for(Employee s: subordinates) {
                    if(s.getSalary() == maxSal) {
                        subOrdinatesListWithHighestSalary.add(s);
                    }
                }
                return subOrdinatesListWithHighestSalary;
            }
        }));
    }
```

**What am I try to achieve:**

The employee class is having `List<Employee> subordinates`. I am trying to get highest salary paid among the subordinates **under** each employee. each employee may or may not have subordinates. If subordinates are not present they are not included in result. If more than one subordinate having same highest salary, all of them should be present in result.

For example, it is similar to get highest paid employee(employees, if salaries match) in each department.

**Employee.java**

```
import java.util.List;

public class Employee{

    private int id;
    private int salary;
    private List<Employee> subordinates;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public Employee setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public Employee setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
        return this;
    }
    public List<Employee> getSubordinates() {
        return subordinates;

    }
    public Employee setSubordinates(List<Employee> subordinates) {
        this.subordinates = subordinates;
        return this;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Employee setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public Employee setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [id=" + id + ", salary=" + salary  + ", name=" + name
                + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

For example for below input:

- employee1(**id:100**) has got employee2,employee3,employee4 and among this
  **employee3** paid highest with **30000** and should be part of output
- employee2(**id:101**) has got employee5, employee6 and among this, **employee5** is highest paid with **20000** and should be part of output
- employee3(**id:102**) has got employee7 and employee8 and both are paid with **same salary** of **16000** and **output should contain both**.
- employee8(**id:107**) has got one subordinate employee9 with salary 12000 and **employee9** should be part of output

  The below is input as explained above:

  ```
   private static List<Employee>  getEmployeeListV1() {
      int i = 100;
      Employee employee1 = (Employee) new Employee().setId(i++).setSalary(10000).setAge(101).setName("emp 1");
      Employee employee2 = (Employee) new Employee().setId(i++).setSalary(20000).setAge(110).setName("emp 2");
      Employee employee3 = (Employee) new Employee().setId(i++).setSalary(30000).setAge(20).setName("emp 3");
      Employee employee4 = (Employee) new Employee().setId(i++).setSalary(10000).setAge(32).setName("emp 4");
      Employee employee5 = (Employee) new Employee().setId(i++).setSalary(20000).setAge(34).setName("emp 5");
      Employee employee6 = (Employee) new Employee().setId(i++).setSalary(15000).setAge(44).setName("emp 6");
      Employee employee7 = (Employee) new Employee().setId(i++).setSalary(16000).setAge(56).setName("emp 7");
      Employee employee8 = (Employee) new Employee().setId(i++).setSalary(16000).setAge(65).setName("emp 8");
      Employee employee9 = (Employee) new Employee().setId(i++).setSalary(12000).setAge(74).setName("emp 9");

      employee1.setSubordinates(Stream.of(employee2,employee3,employee4).collect(Collectors.toList()));
      employee2.setSubordinates(Stream.of(employee5,employee6).collect(Collectors.toList()));
      employee3.setSubordinates(Stream.of(employee7,employee8).collect(Collectors.toList()));
      employee8.setSubordinates(Stream.of(employee9).collect(Collectors.toList()));

      List<Employee> employees = Stream.of(employee1,employee2,
              employee3,employee4,employee5,
              employee6,employee7,employee8,
              employee9).collect(Collectors.toList());
      return employees;

  }
  ```

The below is output:

```
100=[Employee [id=102, salary=30000, name=emp 3, age=20]]
101=[Employee [id=104, salary=20000, name=emp 5, age=34]]
102=[Employee [id=106, salary=16000, name=emp 7, age=56], Employee [id=107, salary=16000, name=emp 8, age=65]]
107=[Employee [id=108, salary=12000, name=emp 9, age=74]]
```

Explaination:

Comment: Here's is a trick/suggestion, when you type such a code in IDE like IntelliJ, it would suggest you all those possible cleanups that you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @nullpointer, but, I have got eclipse unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can change the `keyMapper`  with a method reference (`Employee::getId` or a lambda `employee -> employee.getId()`) and the `valueMapper` (`t -> { ...` ) to a lambda as follows:

```
return employees.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getSubordinates() != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap( //keyMapper
                        Employee::getId,
                        t -> {
                            List<Employee> subordinates = t.getSubordinates();
                            List<Employee> subOrdinatesListWithHighestSalary = new ArrayList<>();
                            int maxSal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                            for(Employee s: subordinates) {
                                if(s.getSalary() >= maxSal) {
                                    maxSal = s.getSalary();
                                }
                            }
                            for(Employee s: subordinates) {
                                if(s.getSalary() == maxSal) {
                                    subOrdinatesListWithHighestSalary.add(s);
                                }
                            }
                            return subOrdinatesListWithHighestSalary;
                        }));
```

You can go further and simplify the method to:

```
return employees.stream()
         .filter(e -> e.getSubordinates() != null)
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId,
                        t -> {
                            int maxSal = t.getSubordinates().stream().mapToInt(Employee::getSalary).max().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
                            return t.getSubordinates().stream().filter(x -> x.getSalary() == maxSal).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));

                        }));
```

and even further to:

```
return employees.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getSubordinates() != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Main::apply));
```

Given you have this method:

```
static List<Employee> apply(Employee t) {
        List<Employee> subordinates = t.getSubordinates();
        int maxSal = subordinates.stream().mapToInt(Employee::getSalary).max().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        return subordinates.stream().filter(x -> x.getSalary() == maxSal).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

Where `Main` refers to the class contain the `apply` helper method.

Comment: Yes. this what exactly I am trying for.

Comment: I like the second approach using method reference. It looks clean.

Comment: @secretsuperstar yes, same here. usually, I always change lambda expressions into method references where possible for conciseness & readability (subjective).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative in which the value mapper requires a single stream pipeline.

It groups the subordinates by their salary into a `TreeMap` sorted in descending order of salary, so the first value of the `TreeMap` is the list of subordinates having the highest salary.

```
public Map<Integer, List<Employee>> getSubordinateHighestSalEmpMapV1(List<Employee> employees) {

    return employees.stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.getSubordinates() != null)
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId,
                                              e -> e.getSubordinates ().stream ()
                                                                       .collect (Collectors.groupingBy (Employee::getSalary,
                                                                                                        ()-> new TreeMap<>(((Comparator<Integer>)Integer::compare).reversed ()),
                                                                                                        Collectors.toList()))
                                                                       .values ()
                                                                       .iterator ()
                                                                       .next ()));

}
```

Comment: interesting, but would like to know if it consumes memory if the subordinates size is pretty big. Thanks @Eran.

Comment: @secretsuperstar Since this solution creates a `Map<Integer, List<Employee>>` from the entire subordinates list, it consumes memory similar to the size of the subordinates list, so depending on how large that list can be, it could consume a large amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Though Aomine has explained how you could optimize the code, I would rather suggest you write it as readable as possible while you are beginning to learn things, hence the inlined would help you understand what actual implementation reside behind the code you've written:

```
public Map<Integer, List<Employee>> getSubordinateHighestSalEmpMapV1(List<Employee> employees) {

    // this is your value mapper
    Function<Employee, List<Employee>> managerToSubOrdinateFunction = new Function<Employee, List<Employee>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Employee> apply(Employee employee) { // given an manager Employee
            int maxSal = employee.getSubordinates().stream() // subordinates as Stream<Employee>
                    .mapToInt(Employee::getSalary)
                    .max()// max salary amongst all subordinates
                    .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            return employee.getSubordinates().stream()
                    .filter(s -> s.getSalary() == maxSal)// filter in only max salary subordinates
                    .collect(toList());
        }
    };

    return employees.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getSubordinates() != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, managerToSubOrdinateFunction));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nullpointer. I am able (at least manage) to write the code using inline implementations. but I find it tricky while I try to use lambda.